Failure theory in graphs and network
Lets say I have the below graph:

The objective is to reach from 1 to 4 (imagine 1 is power plant, 4 is a city, and 2,3,5,6 are power grids). Each link has a probability $F$ of failing and probability $S = 1-F$ of succeeding. What is the overall probability of reaching 1 to 4?
My attempt:
There are 8 possible paths:
a) [1,2,3,5,6]
b) [1,2,3,6]
c) [1,2,4,5,3,6]
d) [1,2,4,5,6]
e) [1,4,5,3,6]
f) [1,4,5,6]
g) [1,4,2,3,5,6]
h) [1,4,2,3,6]
Individual paths, it is simple. For example, P(option a) = $S^4 $ because all 4 must not fail to reach destination.
But I am unable to formulate overall probability of success. Can someone help? Are there any theories/standard ways of approaching these kinds of problems?

There are infinitely many paths. Are you only considering simple paths, or paths that do not intersect? Or paths of uniformly bounded length?

I am considering only paths which don't have cycles. Another way to look at the problem: assume you are at node 1 and are trying to go to node 6 through nodes 2,3,4,5. The links or edges are the roads and they have certain probability of being open/closed

I think that you have a typo somewhere then. Do you mean you are considering simple paths from $1$ to $6$?

I would split it into 4 cases, predicated on whether the crossing edges 2-4 and 3-5 fail or not. If both fail, the problem simplifies to a single span with two potential paths of length 3. If both succeed, you have three spans of length 1, where each span has two potential paths. If only one crossbar fails then you have two spans, one of length 2 and one of length 1, again each with two potential paths. Looked at in this way, it is fairly straightforward to add up all the probabilities.

First, let's look at whether $2$ and $4$ are connected to $1$ via paths inside the left triangle (that is, we consider paths like $1-4$ or like $1-2-4$, but not paths like $1-2-3-5-4$). The possibilities here are:

$C_2$ (only $2$ is connected to $1$) with probability $sf^2$. (Edge $12$ must exist, but edges $14$ and $24$ must not.)
$C_4$ (only $4$ is connected to $1$) with probability $sf^2$.
$C_{24}$ (both $2$ and $4$ are connected to $1$) with probability $3s^2f + s^3$. (At least two of edges $12, 24, 14$ must exist.)

We can similarly compute the probabilities of events $C_3, C_5, C_{35}$ for whether $3$ and $5$ are connected to $6$ in the triangle on the right. (They're identical, by symmetry.)
Now, we can build a $3\times 3$ table of which of these occur, and see what the probability of having a $1-6$ connection is in each case (based on which of the middle edges exist):
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  & C_3 & C_5 & C_{35} \\
\hline
C_2 & s & 0 & s\\
C_4 & 0 & s & s \\
C_{24} & s & s & 2sf + s^2& 
\end{array}
Multiplying these probabilities by the probability of being in each row and column, we get a cumbersome but complete answer: $2(s^2f)^2s + 4s^2f^2(3s^2f+s^3) + (3s^2f+s^3)^2(2sf + s^2)$.

Isn't C2 = $SF$ (Probability 2,1 are connected) x (Probability that 4,1 are not connected)? Similarly, C4 = $SF$ and C24 = $S^2$

Respected Mr Lavrov, explain, please, in details, how have You received $s{f^2}$ relatively of $C_2$ and $3{s^2}f+{s^3}$ relatively $C_{24}$? Is $C$ in those $C_2$ and $C_{24}$ the abbreviation from "cycle"?

@RajaKrishnappa No, because the probability that 1,2 are connected is bigger than just the probability that they're adjacent. For example, event $C_{24}$ (not $C_2$) also occurs if edges $12$, $24$ are present but edge $14$ is not.

@VadimChernetsov See the above comment (and my edit to the answer). I intended the $C$ to be an abbreviation for "connected", but it doesn't really matter - it's just a variable name.

Respected Mr Lavrov, What does $0$ mean at a row $C_2$ and a column $C_5$, at a row $C_4$ and a column $C_3$? What a sense does $s$ have at the same table where $0$ takes a place?

@VadimChernetsov In row $C_2$ and column $C_5$, only $2$ is connected to $1$ in the left triangle, and only $5$ is connected to $6$ in the right triangle. Thus, no matter how the middle edges come out, it is impossible for $1$ to be connected to $6$: the probability is $0$. (In row $C_2$ and column $C_3$, on the other hand, $1$ is connected to $6$ if and only if edge $23$ exists, which has probability $s$.)
